# Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package'

Tags: node.js, json, dependencies

The error in heading is given by VS Code.

I am trying to load a node project and download all its dependencies. But as soon as I put "npm install". It shows the above error. Please provide a solution to this...

I tried all the other solutions already available on Stack overflow but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was with the internet connection. Actually, my LAN connection was bad and it was unable to fetch the internet for downloading these dependencies.

No need to try out all the settings-related solutions, just check the internet and restart VS Code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).